# How to use static method's generated output in other methods?

Tags: python

I don't understand how I am supposed to create static method, which will be run and called only once and which generates some output which will be used be other methods. For example:

```
class Player():

    @staticmethod
    def generateCardDeck():            
        deck = someCalculations

    def someOtherMethod(self):
        something = deck

def main():    
Player.generateCardDeck()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is not going to work, I get error: `NameError: global name 'deck' is not defined`. But if I don't use static method, then how do I create multiple instances of the class, without running that method more than once (considering that other class methods would call generatedDeck() method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can return the deck and use it wherever you want ... or you could make it a classmethod instead

```
class Player():

    @classmethod
    def generateCardDeck(cls):            
        cls.deck = someCalculations


Player.generateCardDeck()
print Player.deck
```

I suppose you could do roughly the same with static method

```
class Player():
    @staticmethod
    def generateCardDeck():            
        Player.deck = someCalculations
Player.generateCardDeck()
print Player.deck
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed, and even both solutions :)